# Dynamically cast in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Let's say I have:

```
ThisClass *castHere = [[ThisClass alloc] init];
```

But I effectively want:

```
ThisClassChosenAtRuntime *castHere = [[ThisClassChosenAtRuntime alloc] init];
```

I'm sure there is some smarter way to go about this. But this is the result I'm after. I already have `castHere` subjected to `setValue forKey` statements. But I want to dynamically setup `*castHere`.

Comment: your question is not clear. Do you want to change the name of ur class?

Comment: A partial answer is to use `id castHere = ...` but the rest of it depends on how you're choosing which class you want to `alloc`.

Comment: I have several classes and want to choose which one is applied to *castHere. There are different property names with each class.

Comment: Repeating, how do you choose?  If it's just a simple `if` or `switch` or something, then the `id` trick is all you need.  If you're trying to decide on a class by using its name (as a string) things get more complicated.

Comment: I'd like to pass the name over as a string. I could use `if` statements or `switch` and get through this. But I'm looking to future proof without revisiting this method. Sorry for making admdrew work overtime. :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C class -> string like: \[NSArray className\] -> @"NSArray"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331983/objective-c-class-string-like-nsarray-classname-nsarray)

Comment: You can't "cast" with a variable type.  Period.  But there's absolutely no need to.

Comment: The type is not varied. The property names are changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can build up the class name as a string, then it's easy.

```
NSString *className = @"ThisClassChosenAtRuntime";
id object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

Note that the return type is `id`. You can call any method from an instance of type `id`.

For something more type safe and if you can rely on a base class than you can.

```
NSString *className = @"ThisClassChosenAtRuntime";
MyBaseClass *object = [[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks Jeffery and Phillip.